# generating conditional combinations in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table:

```
╔═══╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║id            ║name         ║
╠═══╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║   ║ 1            ║a1           ║
║   ║ 1            ║b1           ║
║   ║ 2            ║b2           ║
║   ║ 3            ║c1           ║
║   ║ 2            ║c2           ║
║   ║ 4            ║a2           ║
╚═══╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I have the below query which does the following:

For input (a,b,c) it returns all possible combinations of the form (aX,bX,cX) where X is anything present after "a/b/c" in the records.

(a,b) generates (a1,b1) , (a1,b2) according to my table.

Running this query

```
select t1.id as t1_id, t1.name as t1_name,
t2.id as t2_id, t2.name as t2_name,
t3.id as t3_id, t3.name as t3_name, 
from (select * from table where name like 'a%') as t1 
cross join (select * from table where name like 'b%') as t2 
cross join (select * from table where name like 'c%') as t3
```

[image]

I want to modify the query such that it only returns me the rows where there are no similar ids.

For example 1st row has t1_id = 1, t2_id = 1 so there are two similar ids. This shouldn't be in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select * from (select t1.id as t1_id, t1.name as t1_name,
t2.id as t2_id, t2.name as t2_name,
t3.id as t3_id, t3.name as t3_name, 
from (select * from table where name like 'a%') as t1 
cross join (select * from table where name like 'b%') as t2 
cross join (select * from table where name like 'c%') as t3) as ft
where ft.t1_id<>ft.t2_id and ft.t1_id<>ft.t3_id and ft.t2_id<>ft.t3_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your query by removing the subqueries.  Then use the `where` clause for filtering:

```
select t1.id as t1_id, t1.name as t1_name,
       t2.id as t2_id, t2.name as t2_name,
       t3.id as t3_id, t3.name as t3_name, 
from table t1 cross join
     table t2 cross join
     tablet3
where t1.name like 'a%' and
      t2.name like 'b%' and
      t3.name like 'c%' and
      t2.id not in (t1.id) and
      t3.id not in (t1.id, t2.id);
```